# Action fails when a dynamically created component triggers the event

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm creating a `lightning:input` and a `lightning:select` component dynamically. I'm adding an event handler as `onchange : cmp.getReference('c.myMethod')`

`cmp` is a reference to my parent component, and `myMethod` lives in the parent's controller.

The components are created successfully (so the reference is valid), but after the event is triggered, I'm getting the following error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [a.run is not a function] Failing descriptor: {markup://lightning:select}

The same happens on other events, such as `onblur`.

Comment: seems some syntax error to me right now. Can you add the code where you create this component and where "myMethod" is defined?

Comment: @Rangy thanks,  i've figured it out -- it was a very silly mistake. I was cloning an object using JSON, so the reference function didn't got through. Like this: `var _comp = uiTypeMap[field.fieldType];  var comp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_comp));` . When I've added the reference AFTER the clone, it went through: `comp.attributes.onchange = cmp.getReference('c.c_change');`